# PHP Routing - "Clean" include

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes

I have a PHP routing script, like this:

```
include_once('routing-functions.php');

// pathMatches was imported from routing-functions.php

if(pathMatches('/blog/*')){

    include_once('actual-script.php');

}
```

The problem I have is the following: the functions and global variables from `routing-functions.php` could potentially conflict with the included file. Additionally, I don't want `actual-script.php` to have access to any of the variables of the router.

I am looking for a way to completely wipe the PHP context, so that the file is included as if it were directly requested, so doing the following is not an option because it changes the context/scope in which `actual-script.php` is executed:

```
if(pathMatches('/blog/*')){

    $sandbox = function(){

        include_once('actual-script.php');

    };

    $sandbox();

}
```

Additionally, sending a local request to the file (e.g. with cURL) is also not an option, because it has a negative impact on performance and I want it to run as if it were under the `/blog/` URL.

The problem is easy to solve with .htaccess, however, I need a dynamic solution that uses a PHP router.

If anyone has had a similar problem before or knows of a good solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just redirect to a new file instead of including it?

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge That would change the URL. If you know of a way I can redirect without changing it please let me know because that would solve my problem.

Comment: _"the functions and global variables from routing-functions.php could potentially conflict with the included file"_ - namespacing exists; so you could probably put all those functions & variables into a class, that you then create an instance of, and call the necessary methods. Static methods could help avoid having to "pollute" your global namespace with a variable that holds the class instance; or maybe you could unset the variable at the very end. That's about as "clean" as you can get, I suppose.

Comment: [...] _"Additionally, I don't want actual-script.php to have access to any of the variables of the router."_ - that would for the most part already be the case, if you made the class properties non-public.

Comment: @CBroe This would not completely simulate the behavior that I want (loading the included script as if it were run directly). For example I could not no call `include_once('routing-functions.php');` from the included script if I unset those variables from the router script. This is just an example from the top of my head, there are probably other issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your concern is with inclusion.  Anything you include operates as if it was part of the running script.  Functions can not see global variables unless you specifically inject a variable into them with the global keyword (other than the "super globals").

If your problem is that your routing code is changing "super" global variables, then the question becomes -- why are they doing that just to provide routing?

Many projects have adopted the [Symfony Http Foundation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) component to wrap all the important super globals involved in the HTTP protocol, which is one way you might provide isolation.  Given the wide adoption of this component by many php projects, I would highly recommend taking a serious look at it.

That's as simple as

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

As for providing protection against name conflicts of your functions, just use php namespacing.

```
namespace yourname {
   function foo() {
       echo "yourname foo";
   }

   // rest of your functions
}
```

To call them:

```
yourname/foo();
```